# Why can't I lookup other container by DNS in container

Tags: docker

According to official [Docker's doc](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services), Docker will create DNS server when it started which makes it able to query other container directly by container ID or name.

> containers that use a custom network use Docker’s embedded DNS server, which forwards external DNS lookups to the DNS servers configured on the host.

But when I trying to use `nslookup` directly in container it failed to lookup **but `wget` still success**! What makes it different?

---

Reproduce steps:

```bash
docker network create my-net
docker run -d --name web --network my-net httpd
docker run -it --rm --network my-net busybox
```

after inside `busybox`:

```bash
$ wget -q -O - web
<html>...some content...</html>
```

It works great! but use `nslookup` will failed:

```bash
$ nslookup web
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11:53

Non-authoritative answer:

*** Can't find web: No answer
```

This is my docker's version:

```bash
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.21
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.19.2
 Git commit:        baeda1f82a
 Built:             Tue Oct 25 17:53:02 2022
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           colima
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.18
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.6
  Git commit:       e42327a6d3c55ceda3bd5475be7aae6036d02db3
  Built:            Sun Sep 11 07:10:00 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.6.8
  GitCommit:        9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        5fd4c4d144137e991c4acebb2146ab1483a97925
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:
```

Answer (score 1):

While reproducing your issue I noticed that `nslookup` failed for any query (e.g., `nslookup google.com` also failed. Afterwards, I tried spinning up an ubuntu container on the same network and there both `wget` and `nslookup` worked fine. I do not know the exact reason why this is so, but my guess is that `wget` and `nslookup` rely on some system functionalities which are different for `busybox` and for `ubuntu`.